# Pass User Data to AWS client

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Has anyone successful passed user data to the AWS CLI ?

I have tried various incantations of the following but it does not work.

Docs say string must be base64 encoded : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

The instance logs never indicate the script is executed and chef is installed.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-a73264ce --count 1 --instance-type t1.micro       --key-name scrubbed --iam-instance-profile Arn=arn:aws:iam::scrubbed:instance-profile/scrubbed --user-data $(base64 chef_user_data.sh --wrap=0)
```

chef_user_data.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is inconsistent between the : aws website, the git repo for the tool and the output of the tool itself.

It seems the most up to date info is in the repo pages : https://github.com/aws/aws-cli

The answer is the use something like : --user-data file://chef_user_data.sh

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have. The parameter works as defined, BUT the problem is that the ec2 treats userdata as an opaque data type  - it passes it along as is, with no concrete representation of what it *really* is - that is left to the consuming app process on the instance.  The command line nature of the CLI requires this encoding, but then the receiving process is now obligated to decode it.  And Chef does not. Nor does CloudINIT.net. You can confirm this by checking the instance meta data at

```
    http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
```

Seems like the CLI should encode the base64 userdata payload.

EDIT:  Turns out the documentation is bad, the -user-data param actually accepts a file param, and does the encoding.  --user-data file:///path/to/the/file. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/366